# Проблема с сохранением данных (asp mvc 5+EF)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity-2

Добрый день !
Столкнулся с проблемой передачи и сохранения данных..
У меня есть стандартное действие изменение данных о пользователе :

```
 [Route("Doctor/EditPacientInfo/{name}")]
    public ActionResult EditPacientInfo(string name)
    {

        string username = User.Identity.Name;
        // Fetch the userprofile
        ApplicationUser user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName.Equals(username));
        ViewBag.Email = user.Email;
        // Construct the viewmodel
        ApplicationUser model = new ApplicationUser()
        {          
            PacientInfo = user.PacientInfo
        };
        return View(model);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditPacientInfo(ApplicationUser pacient)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
      //string username = User.Identity.Name;// <--- работает
             string username = pacient.Email;// <---Не работает
            // Get the userprofile
            ApplicationUser user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName.Equals(username));
            // Update fields
            user.PacientInfo = pacient.PacientInfo;
            db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return View(user); // or whatever
        }

        return View(pacient);
    }
```

Суть в проблемы в POST-методе :

Если я использую :

```
string username = User.Identity.Name;
```

То метод работает как надо и все сохраняет в базе данных,НО если я использую :

```
string username = pacient.Email;
```

То метод выдает такую ошибку : 
**Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.**(+строка кода ,где есть сама ошибка):

```
user.PacientInfo = pacient.PacientInfo;
```

В общем ,я хочу сделать так ,чтобы можно было редактировать поля в базе данных не только своего профиля (используя свойство `User.Identity.Name`) ,но еще и других пользователь ( через свойство `pacient.Email`).Возможно ли это вообще или мне как-то по-другому надо выкрутиться (а если по-другому,то как?)

Заранее,спасибо за ответы

Comment: вы воспользуйтесь отладкой и посмотрите, что вам приходит в `ApplicationUser pacient`, судя по ошибке приходит `null`. Поэтому встает вопрос, что вы отправляете в форме.

Comment: @teran , 

using (Html.BeginForm("EditPacientInfo", "Doctor",FormMethod.Post))
{
  
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PacientInfo)

    <input type="submit" value="Save" />

Comment: дак если у вас в форме одно поле только с каким то текстом, то откуда вы хотите получить email и т.п.?

Comment: @teran уже добавил в форму `   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)` - действительно сработало ,спасибо огромное (я наконец полазил и разобрался с пост методом)